# In Excel - Need to separate data from one string, make a new column of this, remove from orig, also remove another piece

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with only one column like this:

```
Col A

1201NSNYC-Brooklyn Group HHCyes

1202NSNYC-Brooklyn Office HHCyes
```

I would like to run a formula on the dataset that would separate for me the 1201, 1202 all rows start out with such a number. the first 4 characters will always start with such a number.

So that the new column would contain 1201, or 1202 and it would delete itself from the original col. also if we can delete the yes at the end (sometimes it is no ) but mostly is yes so it can

be done just for yes. Thank you for your help.

The result after the formula runs is:

```
Col A       Col B

1201         NSNYC-Brooklyn Group HHC

1202         NSNYC-Brooklyn Office HHC
```

Comment: since it is a fixed width, just use text to columns and choose the fixed width and put the line after the forth character.  the it is just a matter of highlighting the second column and use find/replace to replace the `yes` with nothing.

Comment: Use left(A1,4)*1 and mid(A1,5,len(A1)-7) then copy paste special values.

Comment: Could also be a job for Power Query, add new column from examples.

Comment: I see another option of using `FLASH FILL` - In `Column B` type two three rows the first 4 characters (eg. 1201) & press `CTRL E` likewise in `Column C` for the rest of the string excluding the yes or no `NSNYC-Brooklyn Group HHC` & press `CTRL E` , your job is done, now you can delete the `Column A` by pressing `CTRL -` ! `Side Note:` This works for `Excel Users 2013` Till `O365` !

Answer (score 0):

Column A - input data:

```
1201NSNYC-Brooklyn Group HHCyes
```

Column B - the part after the 4-digit code:

```
=MID(@A:A,5,999)
NSNYC-Brooklyn Group HHCyes
```

Column C - the four-digit code:

```
=LEFT(@A:A,4)
1201
```

Column D - strip off any trailing `yes` or `no`:

```
=LEFT(@B:B, LEN(@B:B) - IF(RIGHT(@B:B,2)="no",2,IF(RIGHT(@B:B,3)="yes",3,0))
NSNYC-Brooklyn Group HHC
```

Then hide columns A and B.

You can't write a formula to overwrite the contents of another cell. You'd need to venture into VBA for that.